# Copying Annex style for Conclusions chapter

Tags: chapters, titles, appendices

I am writing a book with 3 parts, and I would like to include a chapter for conclusions that is at the level of the parts, but without a number. Therefore, I have:

```
\chapter*{Conclusions}\label{chapter:conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Conclusions}
```

However, I would like to change the first page of the chapter. Instead of having the same style as other chapters*, I would like to have the "Conclusions" name in a new page, following the style I have for Appendix, where it comes a page that says "Appendices" and then in the next pages the chapters at the Appendices part. I tried to simply put this chapter in between an appendices such as:

```
\begin{appendices}
    \appendixpage
    \noappendicestocpagenum
    \include{Conclusions}
\end{appendices}
```

But of course the name of it is "Appendices". Since I have a real Appendices part later, I cannot modify its name I think. For setting the appendix style I have:

```
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{%
    \bfseries}{%
    \fontsize{60}{35}\selectfont\cantarell\bfseries\scshape\color{Violet!100}\raggedright\centering}{}{}
\def\start@newline{\par}%
\xpatchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{plain}{empty}{}{}
\makeatother
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not simply make ‘Conclusions’ an unnumbered  part?

Comment: Thank you, I think it was the most appropiate way. Do you know how I can get rid off the number page in the part page for only this part?

Comment: This may depend on the document class, but in any case, you may add immediately after `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Bernard recommendation, here is the code:

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\rotatebox{20}{\textcolor{partnumcol}{\thepart}}}
{15pt}
{\fontsize{60}{35}\selectfont\cantarell\bfseries\scshape\color{Violet!100}}
\part*{Conclusions}
```